# How to graph more than one 3D function in the same graph?

Tags: plotting, functions

I am trying to graph the following surfaces so that they are all visible in the same place:

```
z == y^2 - y^3
```

on -3.5 < x < 3.5, -2 < y < 2, -3 < z < 3

```
 (x-3)^2 + y^2 == 0.25
```

on -3.5 < x < 3.5, -2 < y < 2, -3 < z < 0

```
(x+3)^2 + y^2 == 0.25
```

on -3.5 < x < 3.5, -2 < y < 2, -3 < z < 0

How can I graph these three functions on these different intervals?

Comment: `Show[ContourPlot3D[
  z == y^2 - y^3, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -3, 3}], 
 ContourPlot3D[{(x - 3)^2 + y^2 == 0.25, (x + 3)^2 + y^2 == 
    0.25}, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -3, 0}]]`

Answer (score 0):

use Show as @cvgmt said

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[z == y^2 - y^3, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -3,
     3}], ContourPlot3D[(x - 3) ^ 2 + y^2 == 0.25, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -2,
     2}, {z, -3, 0}], ContourPlot3D[(x + 3) ^ 2 + y^2 == 0.25, {x, -3.5, 
    3.5}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -3, 0}]]
```

[image]

and a variant.

```
Show[Plot3D[y^2 - y^3, {x, -3.5, 3.5}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All],
     Graphics3D @ Cylinder[{{3, 0, -3}, {3, 0, 0}}, 0.5], Graphics3D @ Cylinder[
    {{-3, 0, -3}, {-3, 0, 0}}, 0.5]]
```

[image]